# Runtime error when integrating Struts2-Jquery Plugin Datepicker with Netbeans 7.1

Tags: jquery, netbeans, struts2, struts

I use Netbeans IDE v7.1 + Struts 2/XWork plugin with Struts 2.2.3 Libraries and Glassfish Server v3
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39218

I have also integrated Struts2-Jquery plugin from here:
[Plugin Page at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag)

The file I downloaded is: struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.0.jar

First of all, I added it to the project as JAR/Folder Library.

Next, I copied the example code in a JSP page, with the following structure:

```
            <%-- 
                Document   : calendarDemo
                Created on : 18-abr-2012, 17:48:08
                Author     : David32
            --%>

            <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
            <html>
              <head>
                <sj:head locale="es" jquerytheme="lightness"/>
                <title>Datepicker Demo</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <s:form id="form" theme="xhtml">
                  <sj:datepicker id="date0" name="date0" label="With Button Panel" showButtonPanel="true"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date1" name="date1" label="Change Month and Year" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date2" name="date2" label="Custom Button Text" showOn="both" buttonText="Select a Date"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date3" name="date3" label="Show only on Button Click" showOn="button"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date4" name="date4" label="Text after selection" appendText=" (dd.MM.yy)" displayFormat="dd.MM.yy"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date5" name="date5" label="With fast slideDown Animation" showAnim="slideDown" duration="fast"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date6" name="date6" label="With slow fadeIn Animation" showAnim="fadeIn" showOptions="{direction: 'up' }" duration="slow" />
                  <sj:datepicker id="date7" name="date7" label="Show 3 Months" numberOfMonths="3"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date8" name="date8" label="Show Month Array" numberOfMonths="[2,3]"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date9" name="date9" label="Show Years only from 2008 until 2012" yearRange="2008:2012" changeYear="true"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date10" name="date10" label="Button Only" buttonImageOnly="true"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date11" name="date11" label="Without Button" showOn="focus"/>
                  <sj:datepicker id="date12" name="date12" label="With Close Event" onClose="onClose"/>
                </s:form>
              </body>
            </html>
```

The start page as configured in web.xml is of course [b]calendars/calendarDemo.jsp[/b]

Netbeans doesn't detect any errors, as the Datepicker tag is correctly detected and checked.
On the other hand, after getting deployed it gives only an Error 500 Page with the following notice:

```
            org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

Does anybody know if there is anything I am missing to configure this plugin? ANY HELP WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED !

I could gladly paste the whole exception log in another post, because this current post is already too long.

Comment: what URL u hitting when you get this exception? i suspect you are hitting jsp page directly??

Comment: I hit:

http://localhost:8080/TelesismuxWeb/

Which is the location on where the App Container (Glassfish) is listening. I have tested with other JSPs as start pages and they load perfectly.

Comment: you have filter diapatcher configured in web.xml?

Comment: Dear Umesh:

I have googled a lot and couldn't find coincident answers. Some say it is only neccesary to write the following directives inside the JSP that use the tags:

    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

On the other hand, I've read this link: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/webxml.html

In the last part it says that it is not recommended to declare taglibs in web.xml. I am plain confused. I am somewhat new to Struts2. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: No, you need not to declare the tag lib in your web.xml.If you want to use struts2 tag use `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>` and if you want to use jquery tags use `<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>`.Make sure you have configured the struts2 filter dispatcher in your web.xml file.On addition please update your post with web.xml and the library in your classpath

Comment: Here is my web.xml
   http://pastebin.com/EuLR0E1R

Comment: And my libraries as shown in netbeans Project Navigator: 
http://imgur.com/t6FHt

Comment: just few suggestion, since you are using higher version of S2 so DO NOT use deprecated FilterDispatcher in your web.xml rather use `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter ` in filter-class.I am not sure why you using init parameters for Dispatcher.Library are perefectly fine.If this will not work, i suggest you to download sample application war from S2 official site and try customizing that

Comment: Thanks, I am now searching for that example application WAR's to understand better how the taglib can be configured. Nevertheless, I would greatly appreciate if you saw my error log, apparently the App Container CAN NOT load the JAR, why could it be? http://pastebin.com/vvgZvXfz

Comment: that's some well known issue with Jquery plugin http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=238 :( and that's why due to all these mysteries i suggest to use plain Jquery with S2 rather than a plugin

Comment: Looks like "Balu" in this thread had the same issue:
http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/struts2/basic-struts2-project-setup

Comment: I switched to Struts2-Jquery version v3.2.1 and it solved the problem. Those 2 trailing spaces inside struts-plugin.xml are devilish.

Thanks again and I will mark this answer as solved !

Comment: If I may suggest, put the struts2-jquery google user group in the answer for the rest of users to see. I will gladly mark the question as answered.

Comment: great.it solved the issue, but my honest suggestion if you starting with web application go with plain Jquery and it will give you more flexibility and power to control the behavior

Comment: you can answer your own question after 8 hours i believe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by user @Umesh Awasthi, it is a known issue of the [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=238).

A workaround is to downgrade to version 3.2.1 of the plugin.